# Is this an example of incorrect subject/verb agreement?

Tags: significado, letras-de-canciones, concordancia-verbal

A lyric from the wonderful song titled *Pasos de gigantes* by Bacilos:

> Tan solo puedo quedarme como un idiota,
>
> **pensando en cosas que me provoca** hacer contigo en islas perdidas.

My question pertains to the line in bolded font.

Is the subject/verb agreement correct here? If the subject is plural (cosas), then shouldn't the verb be *me provoc**an*** rather than *me provoc**a***?

I understand that songs can be more liberal in adhering to grammar rules. However, this is still great learning experience. And fun, too!

P.S. I'm excited to have learned a use of *provocar* to mean *to like* or *to feel like doing something*. For example:

> Me provoca comer = I feel like eating
>
> No me provoca salir a bailar esta noche = I don't feel like going out
> dancing tonight
>
> ¿Te provoca un café? = Would you like a coffee?

UPDATE:

I work with a native Spanish speaker from Venezuela, via the language learning service Verbling.com. Here's some additional info she shared about this question:

> provocarse = apetecer = to crave, to lust for, to really really want
>
> She very commonly has this usage of provocarse in her everyday speech.
>
> She gave the following example:
>
> Me provoca comerme un helado = I really want to eat me some icecream

I asked, why 'comerme' and not simply 'comer'. She answered, both are correct, 'comerme' adds emphasis.

Any thoughts?

Comment: *¿Te provoca un café?* is not idiomatic. A more idiomatic way to state this is by saying *¿Te dan ganas de un café?* In the same fashion: *me dan ganas de comer*, *no tengo ganas de salir a bailar esta noche.* — *provoca* is quite used as in English with the verb *provoke*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we reconstruct the sentence adding back *cosas*, the result would be:

> Me provoca hacer cosas contigo en islas perdidas.

So *cosas* is the direct object of *hacer*. Its number doesn't need to match with *provoca*.

Note that this usage of *me provoca* as *i feel like* is regional and it may not be understood by everyone. It's listed in [the official RAE dictionary](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UUqWrZ7) as being informal and pertaining to Colombia, El Salvador, and Venezuela, but it's also used at least in Perú:

> 5. tr. coloq. *Col., El Salv. y Ven.* Incitar el apetito, apetecer, gustar.

Comment: Are you suggesting that 'cosas' is the direct object of 'hacer' in the sentence 'pensando en cosas que me provoca hacer contigo en islas perdidas'?

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson no. Formally, in the original sentence the whole *en cosas que me provoca...* is a complement of *pensando*, and *que me provoca...* is a modifier of *cosas*. However, to see if an agreement is needed it is useful to reconstruct the sentence as I did to see where *cosas* would fit.

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson I agree with this answer, and it should be the accepted one. The sentence has its components rearranged, and should be understood as _Tan sólo puedo quedarme como un idiota, pensando en que me provoca hacer cosas contigo en islas perdidas_. Now, what does provoke such feeling? It's not clear in that sentence, maybe the reason is found elsewhere in the lyrics. Just think that _hacer_ needs a direct object. If it isn't _cosas_, then the direct object is missing and the sentence would be wrong: _pensando en cosas que me provocan hacer ¿qué? contigo..._

Comment: @CarlosAlejo note that this usage of *me provoca* is different that what you are used to in Spain. If you say *Me provoca hacer algo*, it just means that you feel like doing it. That's why I added the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo just change *provoca* to *apetece* to get the meaning in peninsular Spanish.

Comment: I also believe there's no disagreement in the OP's sentence. If you change *me provoca* with *me apetece* or *me gustaría*, the grammar is clearer. No one would say *?Cosas que me apetecen hacer contigo* or *?Cosas que me gustarían hacer contigo*. By the same logic, it should be *Cosas que me provoca hacer contigo*, instead of *provocan*.

Comment: @rsanchez I understand, thank you for the tip! But that doesn't change the fact that your answer should be the accepted one. :)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo I agree with that :)

Comment: I think I get it now! Thanks for discussing this in the comments section. This usage of 'provocar' is intransitive, therefore 'cosas' cannot possibly be the direct object of 'provocar'.

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson Oh, no, this usage is transitive. But the direct object is the subordinate *hacer cosas contigo en islas perdidas*. *Cosas* is the direct object in the subordinate. *Me provoca* is an impersonal construction, so it can never be plural.

Comment: @Gorpik al comienzo pensaba que era una construcción impersonal, pero me parece que *hacer cosas...* es el sujeto y *me* el objeto directo, igual que con *me gusta*.

Comment: @rsanchez Sí, creo que tienes razón. El verbo es transitivo, pèro el objeto directo parece ser, como dices, *me*. Aunque no conocía este uso del verbo, parece un sinónimo de *apetecer* y parece usarse igual. En ese caso, podríamos decir *me provocan unas arepas*, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. The subject/verb agreement should've been

> (...) *pensando en cosas que me **provocan*** (...)

In order for this to be *provoca*, the sentence should've been

> (...) *pensando en **una cosa** que me **provoca*** (...)

Songs tend to do modifications in the lyrics. These changes have an effect on the grammar, understandable for Spanish native speakers but confusing for learners.

Anyhow, well spotted!

---

*¿Te provoca un café?* is not idiomatic. A more idiomatic way to state this is by saying *¿Te dan ganas de un café?* In the same fashion: *me dan ganas de comer, no tengo ganas de salir a bailar esta noche.* — **provoca** is quite used as in English with the verb **provoke**.

Comment: I found on SpanishDict.com an entry that says 'provocar' can also mean 'gustar' or 'apetecer'. It also suggests that this usage is used primarily within Latinoamérica. If a native speaker said to you, 'No me provoca la idea,' what would that mean to you?

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson Nothing, it wouldn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

*provocar* can also mean, according to the Spanish Academy of Language, "Excitar en alguien el deseo sexual" (so basically make someone feel sexual desire). I think that in your song this is the meaning given:

> pensando en cosas que me provoca hacer contigo en islas perdidas.
>
> "Thinking about things that sexually excite me to do with you in lost
>   islands"

However, I don't find the sentence in Spanish completely right, there is something that just doesn't click so I don't know. I'm sorry!

Comment: You should've added this as a comment because it doesn't answer the question.